# Does $x \ f(x) \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ (lebesgue integrable) imply $f(x)$ is in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am wondering what conditions must be true so that $$x \ f(x)\in L^1(\mathbb{R}) \Longrightarrow f(x) \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$$

I have been trying to find a counter-example but I have not found any yet.

Any help? Is there a general theorem/rule regarding my confusion?

EDIT: I am interested in the domain being all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: over which domain?

Comment: Over all of the reals I guess.

Comment: How about $f(x)=1/x$?

Comment: Little curiosity: On any closed interval $I$ not containing $0$, then it is true that $xf(x)\in L^1\iff f(x)\in L^1$

Comment: Interesting. How is this proved?

Comment: Let $I\subset \mathbb R^+$ and let $c\in\mathbb R^+$ be its starting point. Then
$$ 0 \le c\int |f(x)| \le \int |xf(x)| < \infty$$
Sorry, it is only $xf(x)\in L^1\implies f(x)\in L^1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the set $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure and the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

Then $\int_{[0,1]}{xf(x) dm(x)}=1$ but $\int_{[0,1]}{f(x)}=\infty$.

For your edit just consider $f(x)=\chi_{[0,1]}\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Ah! So this is not integrable in $[0,1]$ but $x \ f(x)$ is integrable in $[0,1]$

Comment: Yep, I added a few details.

Comment: I guess I should change my question to include that I am interested in all of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @johnmelon multiply by indicator function for all of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @johnmelon just see my edit it is still false.

Comment: haha exactly. qbert beat me by 5 seconds.

Comment: @AlecDiaz-Arias beat me to it. +1

Comment: Ahaha thank you everyone! I understand now

Comment: $\,\,\,- \infty?$